# swift 2 Func Default Type Argument

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, swift-protocols

Given the following code:

```
protocol NetworkWire {
//some requirements
}

protocol EntityRESTRequest {
//some requirements
}

protocol OctupPromisable {
//some requirements
}

final class HTTPNetworkWire: NetworkWire, EntityRESTRequest, OctupPromisable {
//satisfies all requirements
}
```

I now create a func like so,

```
extension NSManagedObject {

func post<T where T:NetworkWire, T:EntityRESTRequest, T:OctupPromisable>(navigationalProperties: String, networkWireType: T.Type = HTTPNetworkWire) -> OctupPromisable {
    //some logic with valid return
    }

}
```

The compiler gives me an error on the post func saying,

**Default Argument of HTTPNetworkWire.Type cannot be converted to type T.type**

Any idea why this is? Although HTTPNetworkWire conforms to NetworkWire,EntityRESTRequest as well as OctupPromisable!

Any ideas will be appreciated. Running Xcode 7.1.1

Comment: Why do you need to default the type to HTTPNetworkWire? Either your function works on any type that conforms to the necessary protocols, or it needs the specific functionality offered by an HTTPNetworkWire object. You should probably create a second function that only takes HTTPNetworkWire objects if you depend on that functionality.

Comment: I want to default to HTTPNetworkingWire so that I can offer convenience on the call site, during Unit Testing I can pass in a mocked object that conforms to these three protocols, but in the actual code, it'll default to HTTPNetworkWire. This is done because HTTPNetworkWire calls are meant to be chainable (Imagine doing a Post, Put and then a Get where the Post, Put and then Get are HTTPNetworkWire requests) and forcing the type to be entered on the call site seems non natural. Besides the usage, any idea why it could not be working ?

Comment: I do not think what you want to do is possible. You can supply default values to a function parameter, but the Swift type system does not support the functionality you are trying to use. A type can either be  concrete, or generic (with or without constraints), but I do not believe there is a way for it to be both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [*Protocol Composition*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID282) without generics:

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    func post(navigationalProperties: String, networkWireType: protocol<NetworkWire, EntityRESTRequest, OctupPromisable>.Type = HTTPNetworkWire.self) -> OctupPromisable {
        //some logic with valid return
    }

}
```

Comment: awesome! It works like a charm. Didn't know about protocol composition. Thanks a lot!